# Help with this Differential Equation? $\cos(x)\frac{dy}{dx}+y-\sec(x)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Couldn't find any help with this online

$\cos(x)\displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}+y-\sec(x)=0$

my final answer was $\displaystyle y = \frac{\tan x+c}{2}$
but I don't think that is correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Make it of type $\frac{dy}{dx} +f(x)y = g(x)$ then find integrating factor and solve.

Comment: Using the general form of a LDE, I.F = $e^{\int sec(x)\, dx}$ as the integration factor, which can be evaluated to I.F = sec(x)+tan(x). You could take it further from here i suppose.

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos x \frac{dy}{dx} +y = \sec x\\
\frac{dy}{dx} + y\sec x = \sec^2 x\\
\implies u\frac{dy}{dx} + uy\sec x = u\sec^2 x$$
where $u$ is the integrating factor with the property that
$$u\frac{dy}{dx} + uy\sec x = \frac{d}{dx}(uy)$$
i.e
$$\frac{du}{dx} = u \sec x\\
\implies \int\frac{du}{u} = \int \sec x \;dx\\
\implies \ln |u| = \ln |\sec x + \tan x| \\
\implies u = \sec x + \tan x\\
\implies y(\sec x + \tan x) = \int \sec^3x + \sec^2x \tan x \;dx\\
\implies y = \frac{\sec x\tan x + \ln|\sec x + \tan x| + \tan^2 x}{2(\sec x + \tan x)}$$